# mbsync with office365 using Thunderbird credentials

Tags: office365, mbsync, mu4e

I want to setup mbsync for download mail from Office365, I've researched about it and I found literacy about using xoauth package and authorize mbsync in Azure, but I'm not an admin in my account.

Then I found I can use existing apps authorization, for example thunderbird one, which I have working well with this account, but I can't figure how to do it.

Right now I have a working gmail account with mbsync and I use it with mu4e.

This is my `.mbsyncrc`

```
IMAPAccount gmail
Host imap.gmail.com
User justme@gmail.com
PassCmd "security find-generic-password -s mu4e-gmail -a justme@gmail.com -w"
Port 993
SSLType IMAPS
SSLVersions TLSv1.2
AuthMechs PLAIN
SystemCertificates no
CertificateFile ~/.mail/certificates/root-certificates.pem

IMAPStore gmail-remote
Account gmail

MaildirStore gmail-local
SubFolders Verbatim
Path ~/.mail/gmail/
Inbox ~/.mail/gmail/INBOX

Channel gmail
Far :gmail-remote:
Near :gmail-local:
Patterns *
Create Near
Sync All
Expunge Both
SyncState *
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Emacs.

Comment: I'm not asking about emacs but mbsync.

Comment: But you had tagged it as `emacs` (until I deleted the tag).

Comment: You're right, sorry